# IBM Case Foundation Email Template New Line Character from Java

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-process-engine

We create tasks containing multiple documents; each document has a number.
I have a string Field (docNums) in the Workflow that contains each document number separated by a delimiter. I have done this as the log / email template will only accept certain types.
I have edited the "stp_new.msg" template to include the docNums field.
No matter what I use as the delimiter, I only get plain text. (as in `<BR>` shows in the email as text "`<BR>`".

What can I use as a delimiter to provide a newline/carriage return? Or am I looking at this all wrong?

The template is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
The field is being created by Java, and Java is also starting the workflow (via ICN). I have tried `<BR>` but CF seems to change it to `&lt;br&gt;`, which Outlook just treats as text.

Comment: I have tried the same in the past but with no luck, please do let us know if you got it to work. Thanks

Comment: Nope.  I have an open PMR with IBM that hasn't had a response for 4 months.  I'm honestly surprised at how bad the default notifications are; seems like something IBM would want to fix.

Comment: @WiredC0der IBM came through and provided an answer that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a list of strings (or String[]) to be displayed as a list inside a Process Engine Notification Template email (i.e. stp_new.msg etc.), the template will need the list set up as a String type variable and surrounded in Pre tags.

**HTML template** (stp_new.msg section):

```
<pre>{$stringContainingList}</pre>
```

The variable will need to be populated with the separator hex("0A")

**Java** (where list is a populated List):

```
String stringList;

for (String s : list){
    stringList = stringList.concat(s).concat(String.valueOf((char)0x0A));
}
```

**Process Engine** (where array is a string[]):

```
arraytostring(array,"","",hex("0A"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Christopher for the answer